# How to load local static html file with QtWebkit

Tags: python, pyside, qtwebkit

Using PySide QtWebkit, I want to show a home html page in QWebView. I tried, but I cannot render it. Here is My code:

**home.html**:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head><title>HomeStart</title></head>
    <body>
        <h3 align="center">Home Page</h3>
        <div>
            <img src="images/welcome.png"/>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**python code**:

```python
self.view = QtWebKit.QWebView()
self.view.load("home.html")  # can not render in webkit.
# QtCore.QUrl.fromLocalFile(QtCore.QFile().fileName()))  # can not render in webkit either.
```

PS: the python code file and the html file are in the same directory. But in webkit it renders it blank.

Answer (score 1):

It makes no difference that the python code file and the html are in the same directory. What matters, is that the html file is in the *current directory*.

If you use an absolute path:

```
self.view.load("/path/to/html/files/home.html")
```

or change to the relevant directory first:

```
os.chdir("/path/to/html/files")
self.view.load("home.html")
```

then it should work okay.

Answer (score 0):

It works fine for me with very simple code. Maybe you have omitted something.

```
import sys
from PySide.QtGui import *
from PySide.QtWebKit import QWebView

class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        QWidget.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        self.view = QWebView(self)
        self.view.load("home.html")

        self.layout = QHBoxLayout()
        self.layout.addWidget(self.view)

        self.setLayout(self.layout)
        self.show()

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
win = Window()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```